# While executing this python code to build banking system, I'm not getting errors but still there is nothing on the console

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a list of clients' name, pins of clients, balances and here I'm trying to register new clients, withdraw and deposit amount to balance:

```py
import sys

nameoftheclients=["Sourabh","Deepanshu","Sushila","Meenu"]
pinsofclients=["0001","0002","0003","0004"]
balancesofclients=[5000,6000,8000,1000]

depositamount=0
withdrawamount=0


#Main module
def mainmodule():
    print("************************************************************")
    print("========== WELCOME TO OUR BANK ==========")
    print("************************************************************")
    print("========== a - OPEN NEW ACCOUNT ============")
    print("========== b - WITHDRAW MONEY ============")
    print("========== c - DEPOSIT MONEY ============")
    print("========== d - CHECK CLIENT'S DETAILS ============")
    print("========== e - QUIT ============")
    print("************************************************************")
    letter = input("Select a Letter from the Above Box menu : ")
    l=letter.lower()
    if l=="a":
        newclientaccount()
    else:
        print("You entered invalid letter!")
        start=input("Do you want to continue?(yes/no): ")
        if start.lower()=="yes":
            mainmodule()
        else:
            print("THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME!")

    
def newclientaccount():
    noofclient = eval(input("Enter no. of Clients to register: "))
    while noofclient>=0:
        clientbalance=0
        name=input("Enter your Name: ")
        nameoftheclients.append(name)
        pin = input("Enter your secure pin of atleast 8 digits:")
        if len(pin)<8:
            print("Please enter atleast 8 digit pin")
            pin = input("Enter your secure pin:")
            pinsofclients.append(pin)
        elif len(pin)>=8 or len(pin)<=20:
            pinsofclients.append(pin)
        else:
            print("Enter a valid pin")
            pin=input("Enter you pin: ")
            pinsofclients.append(pin)
        depositamount = int(input("Enter your deposit amount: "))
        clientbalance=clientbalance+depositamount
        balancesofclients.append(clientbalance)
        print("REGISTRATION SUCCESSFULL")
        details=input("Do you want to see your account details(YES/NO): ")
        if details.lower() == "yes":
            print("YOUR ACCOUNT DETAILS")
            print("NAME: ",name)
            print("BALANCE: ",clientbalance)
        else:
            print("THANK YOU FOR YOR REGISTRATION")
        noofclient=noofclient-1  


mainmodule()
```

I tried to code the banking system with different functions (clientaccount, withdraw, deposit etc.).
I am getting no errors while executing, but still nothing is displayed on the console.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre]. What you have posted is neither minimal nor reproducible.

Comment: I hope it's fine now @khelwood

Comment: That is an improvement. However, it does not seem to reproduce the problem you are describing. If I run your code, I get "WELCOME TO OUR BANK" and loads of other stuff displayed.